# Binning data into a hexagonal grid in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, binning, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to display geospatial data in a hexagonal grid on a Google Map.

In order to do so, given a hexagon tile grid size `X` I need to be able to convert (`{lat, lng}`) coordinates into the (`{lat, lng}`) centers of the hexagon grid tiles that contain them.

In the end, I would like to be able to display data on a Google Map like this:

[image]

Does anybody have any insight into how this is done?

I've tried porting this Python hexagon binning script, [binner.py](https://github.com/coryfoo/hexbins/blob/master/hexbin/binner.py) to Javascript but it doesn't seem to be working properly- the output values are all the same as the input ones.

For the sake of this example, I don't care if there are multiple polygons in a single location, I just need to figure out how to bin them into the correct coordinates.

Code below, ([Plunker here!](http://plnkr.co/edit/QmdNOWR1MqLtAGoH7sba?p=preview))

```
var map;
var pointCount = 0;
var locations = [];
var gridWidth = 200000; // hex tile size in meters
var bounds;

var places = [
  [44.13, -69.51],
  [45.23, -67.42],
  [46.33, -66.53],
  [44.43, -65.24],
  [46.53, -64.15],
  [44.63, -63.06],
  [44.73, -62.17],
  [43.83, -63.28],
  [44.93, -64.39],
  [44.13, -65.41],
  [41.23, -66.52],
  [44.33, -67.63],
  [42.43, -68.74],
  [44.53, -69.65],
  [40.63, -70.97],
]

var SQRT3 = 1.73205080756887729352744634150587236;

$(document).ready(function(){

  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}, zoom: 2});

  // Adding a marker just so we can visualize where the actual data points are.
  // In the end, we want to see the hex tile that contain them
  places.forEach(function(place, p){

    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: place[0], lng: place[1]});
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map})

    // Fitting to bounds so the map is zoomed to the right place
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });

  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  // Now, we draw our hexagons! (or try to)
  locations = makeBins(places);

  locations.forEach(function(place, p){
    drawHorizontalHexagon(map, place, gridWidth);
  })


});


  function drawHorizontalHexagon(map,position,radius){
    var coordinates = [];
    for(var angle= 0;angle < 360; angle+=60) {
       coordinates.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));    
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        position: position,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        geodesic: true
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
}

// Below is my attempt at porting binner.py to Javascript.
// Source: https://github.com/coryfoo/hexbins/blob/master/hexbin/binner.py

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  console.log(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  result =  Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
  console.log("Distance: ", result);
  return result;
}

function nearestCenterPoint(value, scale){
    div = (value / (scale / 2));
    mod = value % (scale / 2);

    if(div % 2 == 1){
      increment = 1;
    } else {
      increment = 0;
    }

    rounded = (scale / 2) * (div + increment);

    if(div % 2 === 0){
      increment = 1;
    } else {
      increment = 0;
    }

    rounded_scaled = (scale / 2) * (div + increment)
    result = [rounded, rounded_scaled];

    return result;
}

function makeBins(data){
  bins = [];

  data.forEach(function(place, p){
    x = place[0];
    y = place[1];

    console.log("Original location:", x, y);

    px_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(x, gridWidth);

    py_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(y, gridWidth * SQRT3);

    z1 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);

    z2 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);

    console.log(z1, z2);

    if(z1 > z2){
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: px_nearest[0], lng: py_nearest[0]});
       console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    } else {
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: px_nearest[1], lng: py_nearest[1]});
       console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);
    }

    bins.push(bin);

  })
  return bins;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a Google Maps API v3 hexagon tiled map, preferably coordinate-based?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761738/how-can-i-make-a-google-maps-api-v3-hexagon-tiled-map-preferably-coordinate-bas)

Comment: Similar question, but that question (and its answers) discuss how to draw the polygons, when I'm more interested in how to bin the data into the appropriate tile.

Comment: What should be done for the overlapping hexagons?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself** (a plunker or jsfiddle is useful, but should not be required to understand/answer the question).

Comment: What are the data points that need to be binned into the hexagons?  Do you want the random hexagons?  Or do you want your random data binned into a hexagon grid (as you indicate in your title)?

Comment: The random locations are just to create example data for the question: In a practical setting I would be binning real-world data into a hexagonal grid. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows what you are trying to do, what the result will look like?  Do you want the random data binned in a hex grid?

Comment: Image added! For the sake of this example, I'm trying to bin the random data into a hex grid.

Answer (score 5):

Use [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#poly).

```
for (var i = 0; i < hexgrid.length; i++) {
  if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place, hexgrid[i])) {
    if (!hexgrid[i].contains) {
      hexgrid[i].contains = 0;
    }
    hexgrid[i].contains++
  }
}
```

Example based off this related question: [How can I make a Google Maps API v3 hexagon tiled map, preferably coordinate-based?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761738/how-can-i-make-a-google-maps-api-v3-hexagon-tiled-map-preferably-coordinate-bas).  The number in the white box in the center of each hexagon is the number of markers contained by it.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/etL21cfn/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var hexgrid = [];

function initMap() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43, -79.5),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);
  createHexGrid();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Seed our dataset with random locations
  for (var i = 0; i < hexgrid.length; i++) {
    var hexbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var j = 0; j < hexgrid[i].getPath().getLength(); j++) {
      bounds.extend(hexgrid[i].getPath().getAt(j));
      hexbounds.extend(hexgrid[i].getPath().getAt(j));
    }
    hexgrid[i].bounds = hexbounds;
  }
  var span = bounds.toSpan();
  var locations = [];
  for (pointCount = 0; pointCount < 50; pointCount++) {
    place = new google.maps.LatLng(Math.random() * span.lat() + bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), Math.random() * span.lng() + bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
    bounds.extend(place);
    locations.push(place);
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place
    });
    // bin points in hexgrid
    for (var i = 0; i < hexgrid.length; i++) {
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place, hexgrid[i])) {
        if (!hexgrid[i].contains) {
          hexgrid[i].contains = 0;
        }
        hexgrid[i].contains++
      }
    }
  }
  // add labels
  for (var i = 0; i < hexgrid.length; i++) {
    if (typeof hexgrid[i].contains == 'undefined') {
      hexgrid[i].contains = 0;
    }
    var labelText = "<div style='background-color:white'>" + hexgrid[i].contains + "</div>";


    var myOptions = {
      content: labelText,
      boxStyle: {
        border: "1px solid black",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: "8pt",
        width: "20px"
      },
      disableAutoPan: true,
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-10, 0),
      position: hexgrid[i].bounds.getCenter(),
      closeBoxURL: "",
      isHidden: false,
      pane: "floatPane",
      enableEventPropagation: true
    };

    var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    ibLabel.open(map);
  }

}

function createHexGrid() {
  // === Hexagonal grid ===
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -78.8);
  map.setCenter(point);
  var hex1 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(point, 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#00ff00", 0.5);
  hex1.setMap(map);
  var d = 2 * 25000 * Math.cos(Math.PI / 6);
  hexgrid.push(hex1);
  var hex30 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 30), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#00ffff", 0.5);
  hex30.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex30);
  var hex90 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 90), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#ffff00", 0.5);
  hex90.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex90);
  var hex150 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 150), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#00ffff", 0.5);
  hex150.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex150);
  var hex210 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 210), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#ffff00", 0.5);
  hex210.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex210);
  hex270 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 270), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#ffff00", 0.5);
  hex270.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex270);
  var hex330 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 330), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#ffff00", 0.5);
  hex330.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex330);
  var hex30_2 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 30), d, 90), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#ff0000", 0.5);
  hex30_2.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex30_2);
  var hex150_2 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 150), d, 90), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#0000ff", 0.5);
  hex150_2.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex150_2);
  var hex90_2 = google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly(EOffsetBearing(EOffsetBearing(point, d, 90), d, 90), 25000, 6, 90, "#000000", 1, 1, "#00ff00", 0.5);
  hex90_2.setMap(map);
  hexgrid.push(hex90_2);

  // This Javascript is based on code provided by the
  // Community Church Javascript Team
  // http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
  // http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

  //]]>
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

// EShapes.js
//
// Based on an idea, and some lines of code, by "thetoy" 
//
//   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams
//   Community Church Javascript Team
//   http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
//   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
//
//   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence
//   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/
//
// Version 0.0 04/Apr/2008 Not quite finished yet
// Version 1.0 10/Apr/2008 Initial release
// Version 3.0 12/Oct/2011 Ported to v3 by Lawrence Ross

google.maps.Polygon.Shape = function(point, r1, r2, r3, r4, rotation, vertexCount, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts, tilt) {
  var rot = -rotation * Math.PI / 180;
  var points = [];
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  var step = (360 / vertexCount) || 10;

  var flop = -1;
  if (tilt) {
    var I1 = 180 / vertexCount;
  } else {
    var I1 = 0;
  }
  for (var i = I1; i <= 360.001 + I1; i += step) {
    var r1a = flop ? r1 : r3;
    var r2a = flop ? r2 : r4;
    flop = -1 - flop;
    var y = r1a * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var x = r2a * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var lng = (x * Math.cos(rot) - y * Math.sin(rot)) / lngConv;
    var lat = (y * Math.cos(rot) + x * Math.sin(rot)) / latConv;

    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + lat, point.lng() + lng));
  }
  return (new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: points,
    strokeColor: strokeColour,
    strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
    strokeOpacity: Strokepacity,
    fillColor: fillColour,
    fillOpacity: fillOpacity
  }))
}

google.maps.Polygon.RegularPoly = function(point, radius, vertexCount, rotation, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts) {
  rotation = rotation || 0;
  var tilt = !(vertexCount & 1);
  return google.maps.Polygon.Shape(point, radius, radius, radius, radius, rotation, vertexCount, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts, tilt)
}

function EOffsetBearing(point, dist, bearing) {
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  var lat = dist * Math.cos(bearing * Math.PI / 180) / latConv;
  var lng = dist * Math.sin(bearing * Math.PI / 180) / lngConv;
  return new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + lat, point.lng() + lng)
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach! But what if I don't already know where the bins are going to be?

Comment: I don't know.  How are you going to determine where the bins are going to be?  how are you going to make your hexagonal grid?

Comment: Given a hexagonal grid size X and a latitude/longitude pair, I'm trying to calculate the closest grid center point to that location. With that information, I would then be able to draw a hexagon of grid size X at that location.

Comment: That works for one point (and one hexagon). How are you going to handle multiple points and a hexagonal grid?

Comment: If the hexagons are drawn to the correct size and location, I would expect them to appear as a grid. I can write logic to deduplicate locations if necessary- my problem is determining the center of the containing hexagon given X grid size.

Comment: What are the constraints on the center of the hexagon (or on the positioning of the hexagonal grid)?  If you have a single set of coordinates, why can't you just put the center of the hexagon there?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at deck.gl and its hexagon layer
https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/h3-hexagon-layer

With the getHexagon function, you can retrieve the H3 hexagon index of each object.

Then,  you can use H3's cellToLatLng function to retrieve the hexagon cell's center coordinates.

But actually, you won't need this step if you just want to create a hexagonal data grid like the one you have shown in the image. You can simply feed the data into the deck.gl hexagon layer and the framework will do the rest to produce the output you want.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32846565)

Comment: @caTS Is it better like this?