# Tiling contiguous polygons in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I'm trying to draw a hexagonal grid in Google Maps. I've come up with a solution  based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470086/3088826) which looks fine at higher zooms, but when zoomed further out I find that the classic "orange-peel" problem occurs: The hexagons no longer fit together like they should:

[image]

[image]

I'm using [this rather cool geodesy library](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy/) to calculate hexagon centers based on an ellipsoidal model (since a 2d model clearly doesn't work on a real-world map) but it's still looking pretty bad when zoomed out.

Preferably, I'd like to draw the hexagons in such a way that they are exactly the same shape and size on screen.

Here's the code I've been working with, also available as a [Plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/K2n7UskGmroZKlOGCdpW?p=preview) I've tried calculating the vertices of each polygon using the same geodesy library that I'm using to calculate the polygon centers, but it still doesn't look right when zoomed out.

```
  var hexgrid = [];

  function initialize(){
    // Create the map.

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 51.5, lng: 0},
      scrollwheel: true,
      zoom: 8
    });


    // This listener waits until the map is done zooming or panning,
    // Then clears all existing polygons and re-draws them.
    map.addListener('idle', function() {

        // Figure out how big our grid needs to be
        var spherical = google.maps.geometry.spherical, 
        bounds = map.getBounds(), 
        cor1 = bounds.getNorthEast(), 
        cor2 = bounds.getSouthWest(), 
        cor3 = new google.maps.LatLng(cor2.lat(), cor1.lng()), 
        cor4 = new google.maps.LatLng(cor1.lat(), cor2.lng()), 
        diagonal = spherical.computeDistanceBetween(cor1,cor2), 
        gridSize = diagonal / 20;

      // Determine the actual distance between tiles
        var d = 2 * gridSize * Math.cos(Math.PI / 6);

        // Clear all the old tiles
        hexgrid.forEach(function(hexagon){
            hexagon.setMap(null);
        });
        hexgrid = [];

        // Determine where the upper left-hand corner is.
            bounds = map.getBounds();
            ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
            sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

            var point = new LatLon(ne.lat(), sw.lng());

            // ... Until we're at the bottom of the screen...
        while(point.lat > sw.lat()){
        // Keep this so that we know where to return to when we're done moving across to the right
            leftPoint =  new LatLon(point.lat, point.lon).destinationPoint(d, 150).destinationPoint(d, 210).destinationPoint(d, 270).destinationPoint(d, 90)

            step = 1;

            while(point.lon < ne.lng()){
              // Use the modulus of step to determing if we want to angle up or down
                if (step % 2 === 0){
                    point = new LatLon(point.lat, point.lon).destinationPoint(d, 30);
                } else {
                    point = new LatLon(point.lat, point.lon).destinationPoint(d, 150);
                }

                step++; // Increment the step

                // Draw the hexagon!
                // First, come up with the corners.
                vertices = [];
                for(v = 1; v < 7; v++){
                    angle = v * 60;
                    vertex = point.destinationPoint(d / Math.sqrt(3), angle);
                    vertices.push({lat: vertex.lat, lng: vertex.lon});
                }

          // Create the shape
                hexagon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    map: map,
                    paths: vertices,
                    strokeColor: '#090',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: '#090',
                    fillOpacity: 0.1,
                    draggable: false,
                });

                // Push it to hexgrid so we can delete it later
                hexgrid.push(hexagon)
            }

            // Return to the left.
            point = leftPoint;
        }
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider that Google Maps is in Mercator Projection.
You have to compensate for the sphere of the globe on the projection.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection