# Android Google Maps hexagonal shape

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to draw a hexagonal shape with text on each shape.

[image]

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761738/how-can-i-make-a-google-maps-api-v3-hexagon-tiled-map-preferably-coordinate-bas) answer but that is in Javascript language. I want to apply it in Android.

How can I achieve the goal described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement functionality similar to one that you mentioned for Google Maps JavaScript API in Google Maps Android API. For this purpose you will need SphericalUtil from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) and also you can add labels as [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) objects. Please have a look at following example that shows how to implement this functionality

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng pos = new LatLng(33.748589, -84.390392);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 7));

        int radius = 40 * 1000; //radius in meters
        drawHorizontalHexagonGrid(pos, radius,6);

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

    private void drawHorizontalHexagonGrid(LatLng startPosition, int radius, int count){
        LatLng curPos = startPosition;
        double width = radius * 2 * Math.sqrt(3)/2 ;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            drawHorizontalHexagon(curPos, radius, "" + (i+1));
            curPos = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(curPos, width,90);
        }
    }

    private void drawHorizontalHexagon(LatLng position, int radius, String label){
        List<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 60) {
            coordinates.add(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));
        }

        PolygonOptions opts = new PolygonOptions().addAll(coordinates)
                .fillColor(Color.argb(35,255, 0,0))
                .strokeColor(Color.RED).strokeWidth(3);

        mMap.addPolygon(opts);

        this.showText(position, label);
    }

    private void showText(LatLng pos, String label) {
        mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().position(pos, 10000)
                .image(
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                        getBitmapFromView(label)
                    )
                )
                .zIndex(1000)
                .transparency(0)
                .visible(true)
        );
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(String label) {
        Bitmap myRefBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.transparent);

        Bitmap myWrittenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myRefBitmap.getWidth(),
                myRefBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(myWrittenBitmap);
        Paint txtPaint = new Paint();
        txtPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        txtPaint.setTextSize(48*scale);
        txtPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        txtPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        //draw ref bitmap then text on our canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(myRefBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawText(label, 5, myRefBitmap.getHeight(), txtPaint);

        return myWrittenBitmap;
    }
}
```

You can see the result in the following screenshot

[image]

The complete sample project is available on Github:

https://github.com/xomena-so/so45856063

Please replace the API key with yours.

I hope this helps!